# Los métodos especiales no me recopila

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Buenas el código lo saque del libro, pero no me recopila, ya use el mismo código del libro y lo analice pero no me funciono. Los metodos especiales get, set y delete no me funciona en mi codigo python y no recopila.

#!C:\python

## -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

```
class Descriptor(Object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.var = ""

  def __set__(self, objeto, valor):
    print("Asignando un valor al atributo")
    self.var = valor

  def __get__(self, objeto, clase):
    print("Obteniendo el valor del atributo")
    return self.var

  def __delete__(self, objeto):
    print("Borrando el atributo")
    del self.var

class Mi_Clase(objet):

  mi_atributo = Descriptor()

  def __init__(self, texto):
    self.mi_atributo = texto

mi_objeto = Mi_Clase("Hola")

texto = mi_objeto.mi_atributo

mi_objeto.mi_atributo = "adios"

del mi_objeto.mi_atributo

print(texto)
input()
```

Comment: Define "no recopila". Tienes que especificar cual es el resultado esperado y cual es el que obtienes.

Comment: Buen día, `object` (Es con minúscula) está mal escrito ambas veces, por eso no funciona. Al copiar código siempre fijate que lo copies bien. Por otra parte "recopilar" significa "Juntar o reunir varias cosas dispersas", el verbo que buscas es "compilar" pero Python no es un lenguaje compilado es interpretado [artículo de ayuda](https://blog.makeitreal.camp/lenguajes-compilados-e-interpretados/)

Comment: `Object` es la clase base por *default*; no es necesario decirlo explícitamente. Basta con `class Descriptor`.